# How to compare strings in textboxs with Matlab

Tags: matlab, strcmp

I would like to compare strings in textboxs of rock, paper and scissors game. After comparing, display the result in another textbox. But it does not compare. Can someone please help me?

```
if strcmp('Rock'==get(handles.computer,'string'),'Rock'==get(handles.player,'string'))
    set(handles.result,'string','Draw');
elseif strcmp('Rock'==get(handles.computer,'string'),'Paper'==get(handles.player,'string'))
    set(handles.result,'string','Player wins');
elseif strcmp('Rock'==get(handles.computer,'string'),'Scissors'==get(handles.player,'string'))
    set(handles.result,'string','Computer wins');
elseif strcmp('Paper'==get(handles.computer,'string'),'Rock'==get(handles.player,'string'))
    set(handles.result,'string','Computer wins');
elseif strcmp('Paper'==get(handles.computer,'string'),'Paper'==get(handles.player,'string'))
    set(handles.result,'string','Draw');
elseif strcmp('Paper'==get(handles.computer,'string'),'Scissors'==get(handles.player,'string'))
    set(handles.result,'string','Player wins');
elseif strcmp('Scissors'==get(handles.computer,'string'),'Rock'==get(handles.player,'string'))
    set(handles.result,'string','Player wins');
elseif strcmp('Scissors'==get(handles.computer,'string'),'Paper'==get(handles.player,'string'))
    set(handles.result,'string','Computer wins');
elseif strcmp('Scissors'==get(handles.computer,'string'),'Scissors'==get(handles.player,'string'))
    set(handles.result,'string','Draw');
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the way you compare the string of the two textboxes:

```
if strcmp('Rock'==get(handles.computer,'string'),'Rock'==get(handles.player,'string'))
```

In this statement:

```
'Rock'==get(handles.computer,'string')
```

you compare element by element the characters of the two strings.

This comparison returns an array of type `logical` (`1` if the i-th character of the first string is equal to the i-th character of the second string, `0` otherwise)

Notice that if the two strings are of different length, you will get an error such as `Matrix dimensions must agree.`

The same applies to the second part of the statement:

```
'Rock'==get(handles.player,'string')
```

In case both the *computer* and the *player* insert the same string (e. g. *Rock*), you are then using `strcmp` to compare two `logical` arrays and, it fails.

`cases`You have, therefore, to directly compare the strings.

A possible solution could be to use a `switch` statement:

- first you get the *computer* and the *player* strings
- then you convert the strings to `lower case` (*Rock* and *rock* are ... the same)
- then you can concatenate the two string (e. g. _rock_rock_)
- the `cases` of the `switch` holds the differnt combinations

A possible implementation could be:

```
% Get the Computer string (in lower case)
computer=lower(get(handles.computer,'string'))
% Get the Player string (in lower case)
player=lower(get(handles.player,'string'))
% Concatenate the two string
res=[computer player]
% Check for the different combination
switch(res)
   case 'rockrock'
      set(handles.result,'string','Draw');
   case 'rockpaper'
      set(handles.result,'string','Player wins');
   case 'rockscissor'
      set(handles.result,'string','Computer wins');
   case 'paperrock'
      set(handles.result,'string','Computer wins');
   case 'paperpaper'
      set(handles.result,'string','Draw');
   case 'paperscissor'
      set(handles.result,'string','Player wins');
   case 'scissorrock'
      set(handles.result,'string','Player wins');
   case 'scissorpaper'
      set(handles.result,'string','Computer wins');
   case 'scissorscissor'
      set(handles.result,'string','Draw');
   otherwise
      set(handles.result,'string','Invalid text');
end
```

[image]

Hope this helps,

Qapla'

Comment: What does this mean "SWITCH expression must be a scalar or string constant" ? Now when I type if isscalar(res) it does not show the result. I did this in another matlab file not the other one that I did wrong.

Comment: I don't understand your question: the [switch](uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html) function evaluates the expression (in this case the string `res`) and executes the statements in the `case` block that matches the condition, otherwise, executes the `default` statements in the `otherwise` section. Are you getting any error implementing the proposed code? Why are you checking `isscalar(res)`?

Comment: Yes. The error said "SWITCH expression must be a scalar or string constant" .

Comment: In the above example the `switch` expression is actually a `string constant`: the `res` string resulting from the concatenation of the `computer` and `player` strings extracted from the textboxes. Did you used in your code also the first three line od code of the above example? Which string did you put in the two textedit boxes?

Comment: Yes, I did. Ok, I have 2 files. One is for testing and another is the real one. The real one(game) has images with textboxes that tells that what are they. The testing one is for only test comparing strings like you have done and it works. But in the real one, their is an errors and it saids "SWITCH expression must be a scalar or string constant".

Comment: You should post the code that generates the error, otherwise it is impossible to understand the problem. Anyway, did you debug it? What are the string in the two textboxes? What is the string `res` resulting from the concatenation of the string extracted from the textboxes?

Comment: SWITCH expression must be a scalar or string constant.

Error in RPS>loadCam (line 216)
switch(res)

Comment: How do you set the variable `res` used in the `switch`? Did you debug the code? Waht is the content of `res` when the error is generated?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @il_raffa, I would suggest mapping `rock`, `scissor`, `paper` to `[1,2,3]`, respectively. Then subtract the value of `computer` from the `player`.

Then you can do `if, else if, else` easily.

```
if ismember(player - computer, [-1 2]) %This mean player got a 
     'player wins'
elseif ismember(player - computer, [1 -2])
     'computer wins'
else
     'draw'
end
```

When there are only 9 conditions, `switch, case` may not be a big deal but if the number of conditions was higher, such a technique would make the work easier.